# Docker container instance in Terraform without specifying any port mapping

Tags: terraform

I got an issue in the following terraform parent module:

### Parent_module

```py
module "docker_container" {
  source = "../modules/docker_container"
  for_each = { 
    for container_name in local.container_name : container_name.container_name => container_name }
  container_name  = each.value.container_name
  container_image = each.value.container_image
  env_variables = each.value.env_variables
  network_name = each.value.network_name
  internal_port = each.value.internal_port 
  external_port = each.value.external_port
}
```

also my locals, where I call my variable file beneath

### locals

```py
locals {
    
    container_name = yamldecode(file("../live/xxxx/xxxxx.yml"))
   
}
```

### variables

```py
- container_name: "xxxxxx"
  container_image: "xxxxxxx"
  env_variables:
    - "xxxx"
    - "xxxx"
    - "xxxx"
    - "xxx"
  network_name: "xxx"
  external_port: 80
  internal_port: 8080
```

when I am calling a docker_container child module as below

### Child_module

```py
resource "docker_container" "container" {
  name  = var.container_name
  image = var.container_image

  
  ports {
    internal = var.internal_port 
    external = var.external_port
  }
  

  env = var.env_variables
  
  networks_advanced {
    name = var.network_name
  }


  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}
```

I need to specify internal and external ports

How I can iterate through the variables, I provide via locals (yml.file), and create multiple instances of docker_containers without always specifying internal/external ports mapping..?

This is needed because I have some dockers where I need to specify port mapping and some others where I don't.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried already? Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question.